# Way to modify array of object in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, object

I am doing project to make list of passenger details, so I am storing the passenger Object list in an array as follows :

`var object = {`
`passengerDetails[0].age: "22"`,
`passengerDetails[0].gender: "M"`,
`passengerDetails[0].name: "asdfasdf"`
`passengerDetails[1].age: "23"`,
`passengerDetails[1].gender: "F"`,
`passengerDetails[1].name: "xxx"`
`}`

But What I need is as follows :

`var object = {`
`"passengerDetails" : [{"age":"22", "gender" :"M" ,"name" : "asdfasdf"},`
`{"age":"23", "gender" :"F" ,"name" : "xxx"}] }`

Is there any way for the above conversion ? Alternate way is also welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually after serializing the form I got first said output, but what i need is the second said output. My form has plenty no of variables, so i serialized. Any **custom method** to give above said `object` as Input and I got second said output.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is correct if you change the first `:` to a `=` (I'm assuming `passengerDetails` is a variable), and ideally add a `;` at the end:

```js
var passengerDetails = [
  {
    "age": "22",
    "gender": "M",
    "name": "asdfasdf"
  },
  {
    "age": "23",
    "gender": "F",
    "name": "xxx"
  }
];
snippet.log(passengerDetails[0].age); // 22
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```